# How to visualize PostGIS data(geography) in QGIS?

Tags: postgis, postgresql

I've created a table that stores spherical circles located all over the globe. But I'm not able to view this data in QGIS.
This is my table:

```
CREATE TABLE circles(gid serial PRIMARY KEY, the_geog geography(POLYGON,4326) );
```

I've inserted the data like this:

```
INSERT INTO circles (gid, the_geog) VALUES (1, geometry(ST_Buffer(geography(ST_GeomFromText('POINT(48.732084 -3.459144)')), 1000)));
```

I'm getting this error in the console:

```
dbname='TestGIS' port=5432 sslmode=disable table="public"."circles" sql= is an invalid layer - not loaded
```

Can anybody explain what I'm doing wrong ?

Comment: What versions of QGIS and Postgis are you using? Using Postgres 9.5 (x64), Postgis 2.2, QGIS 2.14.1 I copy-pasted your queries and was able to add and visualise the layer from QGIS.